# Usage of apostrophe 's

Tags: grammar

Do I need to use apostrophe 's in the following sentence?

- I left my job in 2007 after a misunderstanding between me and the manager of the company. I joined the the company again in 2009 after my **friend*'s* becoming** the new manager of the company.

I know we can say the following:

- I left my job in 2007 after a misunderstanding between me and the manager of the company. I joined the the company again in 2009 after my **friend became** the new manager of the company.

But should I use apostrophe 's if I use a gerund?

Comment: Your very use of apostrophes is incorrect. You follow the word _apostrophe_ with a space and... an apostrophe! (Why?) The 's ending is for posessives and abbreviation of is, has, etc, not for plurals.

Comment: The plural of *apostrophe* is *apostrophes*. By actually using an apostrophe before the *s*, you are turning it into a possessive. (*"Apostrophe's **what**? What does Apostrophe own?"*

Comment: He's being a little tautological perhaps, but I wouldn't call it incorrect. It's like saying "Is it alright to use the ampersand & here?"

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there are situations when you can use the possessive with a gerund.  A gerund is a noun like any other:

> As a dedicated vegan, I try not to comment on my **friends' eating habits**.

This works because "eating habits" is a well-known compound noun that just happens to start with a gerund.

Most of the time, however, the result is confusing or awkward.  Your first sentence is a good example. "After my friend's becoming ..." is a complicated way to make what should be a simple, declarative statement.

Another example:

> She appreciated her **friend's welcoming** of the new families into their community.

Again, "her friend's welcoming" is an inelegant phrase. In general, it's better to keep it simple:

> She appreciated that her **friend welcomed** the new families into their community.

or rearrange it to use a more common noun:

> She appreciated her **friend's welcome** of the families into the community.

This last option is something you can do with your example:

> I joined the the company again in 2009 after my **friend's appointment as** the new manager of the company.

Side note: As in any language, there are many ways to say something in English.  Different people have different writing styles and might prefer to use the possessive gerund to convey shades of meaning.  For example, ["welcoming"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/welcoming) is also an adjective that means:

> behaving in a polite or friendly way to a guest or new arrival

You might choose to write "her friend's welcoming" to suggest that this quality of her friend's personality, or just because you think it sounds better than "welcome".